# ensime sbt dependency issue

Tags: scala, sbt, ensime

im trying to use ensime with sbt but when i try in the command line

```
  sbt ensimeConfig


 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 [warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
 [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 [warn]     :: org.ensime#sbt-ensime;1.10.0: not found
 [warn]     :: io.get-coursier#sbt-coursier;1.0.0-M14: not found
 [warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#sbt-ensime;1.10.0: not found
unresolved dependency: io.get-coursier#sbt-coursier;1.0.0-M14: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#sbt-ensime;1.10.0: not found
```

i don't know what is the problem i have good internet connection and and alot sbt packages are downloaded

note: im using a clean project with activator new basic scala program

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['ensime generate' is not a valid sbt command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537187/ensime-generate-is-not-a-valid-sbt-command)

Answer (score 0):

well i looked in maven repo and found that these plugins only available for scala 2.10 while i was working with 2.11.7
so i changed it to 2.10.6 and it worked fine